# Scala find min/max in a sequence of tuples

Tags: scala, max, min, reduce

I would like to have a `val the_min` that would get the minimum value from a sequence defined as:

```
def datesSequence(): Seq[(String, String, String)] = {
....
}
```

As a formatted output of the sequence:

```
println(datesSequence().map { case (y: String, m: String, d: String) => s"$y-$m-$d" } mkString(", ") )
```

> 2017-05-13, 2017-05-12, 2017-05-11, 2017-05-10, 2017-05-09,
>   2017-05-08, 2017-05-07, 2017-05-06, 2017-05-05, 2017-05-04,
>   2017-05-03, ... 2017-06-02

My attempts to have a simple reduce on such structure to get a minimum or maximum did not work..

The desired output for the above example (dates between 2017/05/13 and 2017/06/02) would be:
**min**: 20170513 **max**: 20170601

thanks

Comment: why didn't your attempts work? what was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Now that the tuples make a `yyyyMMdd` form, you can get the min value by:

```
datesSequence().minBy(_.toString)
```

As a side note, while it is a quick-and-dirty solution with the given condition, think about representing your dates as true `Date`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply apply `min`, `max` to your list of date strings provided if they are properly formatted (e.g. in padded yyyymmdd format):

```
val dateSeq: Seq[(String, String, String)] = Seq(
  ("2017", "5", "16"),
  ("2017", "6", "1"),
  ("2017", "5", "13"),
  ("2017", "5", "28"),
  ("2017", "6", "2"),
  ("2017", "5", "20"),
  ("2017", "5", "25")
)

// Not needed if month and day in the source list were already properly padded
def padded(s: String) = if (s.length < 2) "0" + s else s

val formatedDateSeq = dateSeq.map{ case (y, m, d) => y + padded(m) + padded(d) }

formatedDateSeq.max
// res1: String = 20170602

formatedDateSeq.min
// res2: String = 20170513
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple really. Just tell the `minBy()` and `maxBy()` methods how to measure the tuple.

```
dateSeq.minBy(x => x._1+x._2+x._3) //res0: (String, String, String) = (2017,05,03)
dateSeq.maxBy(x => x._1+x._2+x._3) //res1: (String, String, String) = (2017,06,02)
```

Comment: Why not just `dateSeq.min`, `dateSeq.max`?  If you are so eager to do the guy's homework for him, you could have at least showed him how to do it on one pass.